# How to read/resolve mif file created by Mapinfo

Tags: java, c#, gis, mapinfo

I want to resolve some .mif files with C# or Java to get the coordinate information.But there are few documents about this kind of file and I'm a newcomer ... Maybe I can resolve them simply using InputStream but I want to know how others do this :P

Also if you know the meaning of each line please tell me :-D

With great pleasure.

The head of mif file like this:

```
Version   300
Charset "WindowsSimpChinese"
Delimiter ","
CoordSys Earth Projection 1, 104
Columns 9
  guid Char(64)
  sr_id Char(64)
  mp_id Char(64)
  name Char(128)
  catalog Char(9)
  floor Char(8)
  tag Char(254)
  elevation Char(6)
  rank Char(2)
Data
```

And the data like this:

```
Region  1
  5
116.312476 40.027556
116.312302 40.027541
116.312292 40.027609
116.312468 40.027623
116.312476 40.027556
    Pen (1,2,0) 
    Brush (1,0,16777215)
    Center 116.312384 40.027582
```

Comment: There is a free open source C++ library which you could use to read/write MIF/MID files. http://mitab.maptools.org/

Comment: @T_Bacon  Thank you very much!  It works. :)  And  I think this library will also help me in my next work. Good resource !

Comment: Did you check the documentation: [MapInfo Pro User Guide](http://reference1.mapinfo.com/software/mapinfo_pro/english/16.0/MapInfoProUserGuide.pdf), chapter Appendix D: MapInfo Map Interchange Format